# Extract values from nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

How to extract values from nested dictionary to a new output?

I have books `season_n`, `ch_number_n`, `ch_name_n` and `pages_n`:

```py
text = {
    1: {
        1: {"ch.name": "The Boy Who Lived", "pages": "146"},
        2: {"ch.name": "The Vanishing Glass", "pages": "126"},
    },
    2: {
        1: {"ch.name": "The Worst Birthday", "pages": "129"},
        2: {"ch.name": "Dobby's Warning", "pages": "125"},
    },
}
```

How can I get the output?

```
Watched Season <season number> Chapter <ch_number>:<ch_name>,<page>
```

```
Watched Season 1 Chapter 2:The Vanishing Glass,126
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: You can't get the required output from the provided nested dictionary, because the value 50 isn't there.

Answer (score 1):

```
text = {
        1:{
           1:{'ch.name' : 'The Boy Who Lived', 'pages' : '146'},
           2:{'ch.name' : 'The Vanishing Glass' , 'pages' : '126'}
        },
        2:{
           1:{'ch.name' : 'The Worst Birthday', 'pages' : '129'},
           2:{'ch.name' : "Dobby's Warning" , 'pages': '125'}
        }
} 
output = ''
for key1, value1 in text.items():
    for key2, value2 in value1.items():
        output += "Watched Season "+str(key1)+' Chapter '+str(key2)+':'+value2['ch.name']+','+value2['pages']+'\n'
#print(output, end='')
#print(' ---------- ' )
print(output.split('\n')[2])
```

gives:

```
Watched Season 2 Chapter 1:The Worst Birthday,129
```

Comment: Thanks. But if I want the 'Watched Season 2 Chapter 1:The Worst Birthday,129' only, how can I get it?

Comment: Choose a dictionary entry with an index starting from 0 to get the Chapter you want. The index of the requested dictionary entry is 2 ( count from top starting with 0) and you get it with: `print(output.split('\n')[2])`